# Dynamic Tabs in jsf based on query results

Tags: jsf, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I have a situation where i have a table with multiple department entries. I will run a DISTINCT query on department names and have to create tabs in jsf page for each of the departments.When i add a new department in the table , then it should dynamically create a tab for that department.
How to achieve this?

Your help is much appreciated..Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I presume your menu is based on view objects. If that's the case, then new menu tab will be available on the next time the user logs in (in case you use security) , or if you close and re-open the browser.

If you want a different behaviour, you need to code your way out: offer a 'refresh' button from where you may do a call 'Execute'  action to refresh the menu on demand.
An option  to get the new menu visible immediately ( though not recommended from performance perspective) would be to set the attribute CacheResult=false on the pageDef's iterator pointing towards your view object.